# getting facebook thumbnail profile picture

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone know how I can get a thumbnail/avatar of a facebook user using the javascript sdk?

I know to get the full size picture I can do the folllowing:

```
//Get a list of all the albums
FB.api('/me/albums', function (response) {
  for (album in response.data) {

    // Find the Profile Picture album
    if (response.data[album].name == "Profile Pictures") {

      // Get a list of all photos in that album.
      FB.api(response.data[album].id + "/photos", function(response) {

        //The image link
        image = response.data[0].images[0].source;

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Not sure on how to get the thumbnail/avatar size. Something like a 50x50 size

Comment: Isn't there an API rate limit on any of those methods? I heard something about 600 requests per 600 seconds, this is not scaleable. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: wondering for the same thing as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also just use an `<img>` tag with a special URL to do the same thing:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture?type=square" />
```

Comment: good answer ... I'm using it often ... Just a little precision from Facebook doc : (use ?type=small | normal | large to request a different photo)

Comment: I believe it's `square`, `large` or `small`. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, under Reading -> Pictures.)

Comment: I don't know, I copy-pasted from the doc ... which is known to be always acurate (**NOT**)

Comment: This only works if you are requesting the picture for a 'user'.  If you need to get the avatar for a page you'll need to try something else. (still in search of the solution!)

Comment: @Volcanic no, this should work for pages too. Some pages that are age-gated (like alcohol-related pages) require an access token passed as a GET parameter.

Comment: Potential gotcha: this technique doesn't work for published pages, even if you're logged in with an administrator account. The graph URL simply redirects you to a placeholder image instead: https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/_xS7LcbxKS4.gif

Comment: @Alhadis: depends on the page. If it's age- or country- gated, you're right, like https://graph.facebook.com/Budweiser/picture. Pages that aren't gated work fine, like https://graph.facebook.com/starbucks/picture.

Comment: ... FFS, I meant "UNPUBLISHED pages"... how could I have not picked up on that typo? :( Ugh, somebody pass me the "Edit comment" button. *fumbles around for it*

Answer (score 3):

As of August 2012, you can define custom dimensions for the user thumbnail, e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?width=WIDTH&height=HEIGHT`. Find out more, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to accomplish the same thing:

```
FB.api(
      {
       method: 'fql.query',
       query: 'SELECT name,email,pic_small FROM user WHERE uid=' + uid
       // uid is the id of the user.
      },
      function(response) {
         var user = response[0];
         // user.pic_small contains the url for the small sized profile pic
      });
```

Comment: Update (July 2014): FQL is deprecated and won't be supported beyond Version 2.0 of the Facebook Platform API ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile_pic/)).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the UID of the person, you can easily get the image. For example, my profile image URL should be graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1375341351/picture?type=small (now change the type parameter and enjoy different sizes.. cheers... sizes can be small, normal, album, large, square